# Weblogic datasource test connection on startup

Tags: testing, connection, datasource, weblogic-10.x

We have multiple data sources in our weblogic(10.3.5) connecting to different DB servers (we have quite a few DB servers).
If any one of the DB server is down or the DB password changed/expired, the complete managed server is going to admin state.

I think this is because weblogic is trying to test the datasource while its coming up and since its unable to initialize the datasource, the server is not starting and going into admin mode.

Is there a way we can disable this feature? Our application has a logic to check the datasource if it is active (test connection) before the user starts using that datasource.

I am aware of weblogic JMX MBeans which can be used to disable/suspend. But to do this, we need to write a startup class. Not sure if this works, but If there's a configuration that we can set, we would prefer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Connection Pool tab for the datasource, set the Initial Capacity to 0. This will stop the initial check and the server should start properly.